# How to do Rails Active Record query for this

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to filter my model in my controller by country. My model has 4 location fields,

```
loc1, loc2, loc3 and loc4
```

The country is in either `loc3` or `loc4`. If the country is in `loc3` then `loc4` is blank.

I have a method on my model called `country` which returns the country but I cannot use that in my Active Record query.

How can I do an AR query that looks at loc3 and loc 4 and if loc4 is blank then it uses loc3 ad if loc4 is not blank it uses loc4.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` function if you are using postgres or mysql

```
Model.select("COALESCE(loc4, loc3) AS location")
```

And in your controller, you can say

```
model.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal where method (if by blank you mean `""`).

```
Model.where(country: (loc3 || loc4))
```